# How to remove woocommerce_breadcrumb() from do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

Tags: php, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I want to remove woocommerce_breadcrumb from `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' )` in WordPress. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action is added at [L47 of wc-template-hooks.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/1bb88d0a50c9c3a0426c2be1145f9019089915bf/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L47). So just remove action at the same priority.

Add this to your child theme functions.php file or as a separate plugin.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
```